# How to downcast from AnyObject to UInt16?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pass some values into a function that accepts UInt16 values as arguments.

I'm receiving the values by querying a database through Parse. The query returns an object (which I know to be an integer) of type AnyObject! and in order to pass it into the function, I must convert it to a UInt16. However, it seems like Swift doesn't like this, saying that UInt16 does not conform to the AnyObject protocol.

I can downcast the type AnyObject! to an Int successfully, but I cannot cast that Int into a UInt16.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can cast from a `AnyObject` to an `Int` with the `as` type cast operator, but to downcast into different numeric types you need to use the target type's initializer, i.e:

```
var o: AnyObject = 1
var n: Int = o as Int
var u: UInt8 = UInt8(n)
```

Comment: In Swift you "cast" by using an initialiser of the data type you want to convert to, i.e. `NewType(foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is adding an ! after as during conversion.

For example,

```
var amount : Int = user["Amount"] as! Int
```

I hope it helps...